# Zero is usually right for a protocol?

Tags: c, gnu

I have been going through the GNU, libc manual on using the sockets. As per to the documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Creating-a-Socket.html)

Exact wording from the documentation is,

> zero is usually right for protocol.

I have seen several examples of code where engineers have put 0 for the protocol when implementing a socket regardless of the protocol in use!

```
 int socket (int namespace, int style, int protocol)
```

May I know, What does the author mean by above statement ? I could sense that there are situations in which 0 might not be the correct answer as per to the author's statement, If so, would it be possible for someone to elaborate on such scenarios ? Most importantly where do we get the value for protocol ? Is there any standard to refer to for protocol numbers ?

Comment: _"Specifying a protocol of 0 causes socket() to use an unspecified default protocol appropriate for the requested socket type."_ [src](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/socket.html)

Comment: The answer to your question can be obtained merging @JohnnyMopp 's statement to the info contained [here](https://linux.die.net/man/2/socket): _"Normally only a single protocol exists to support a particular socket type within a given protocol family, in which case protocol can be specified as 0. However, it is possible that many protocols may exist, in which case a particular protocol must be specified in this manner."_ Since the most relevant info is the previous one, is their right to write an answer out of this.

Comment: Summarizing, in case of `protocol=0` we have that the protocol is undefined and a default proto is chosen **but** if only one protocol is implemented (and that's **usually** the case) it's actually not undefined at all. So, saying that passing 0 is **usually** ok makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The valid values for `protocol` is dependent on the `namespace` used and the kernel the program is running on.

I assume, since the question is tagged `gnu`, that you are running under linux. You may then find a list of valid namespaces, and links to documentation of those namespaces with `man 'socket(2)'`. For instance, you may find documentation for the internet namespaces `AM_INET` and `AM_INET6` under `man 'ip(7)'` and `man 'ipv6(7)'`

Reading the `ip(7)` manpage you may then see that `AM_INET` supports protocols `IPPROTO_TCP` and `IPPROTO_SCTP` for stream sockets, and `IPPROTO_UDP` and `IPPROTO_UDPLITE` for datagram sockets.

If you want to dig further, the different protocols also have their own manpages